# Regex to match offsite anchor tags

Tags: regex

I'm attempting to match html Anchor tags to inject a Target="_top" attribute for offsite links. This is part of a tool set to process sites created in a tool that doesn't support setting a Target attribute.

`<a.*?>` works for matching opening and self closed Anchor tags.
I'd like to only match Anchor tags that contain: href="http
And I'd like to exclude Anchor tags that contain: Target="

Since these are html files, multiple Anchor tags will be on a single line, so a pattern like: `<a.*?href="http.*?>` will start at the first

I did find a neat jsfiddle like site for regex, here's what I'm working on:
http://regexr.com/394mf

Html:

```
<a href="/absolute_url/whatever">1</a>
<a class="test" href="test.html">a link</a><a class="test" target="_top" href="http://www.domain.com/">off site</a>
<a href="http://www.domain.com/" class="test">off site</a>
<a class="navbar-link" href="https://www.domain.com/signup">Sign-up</a><a class="navbar-link" href="https://www.domain.com/shop">
<a href="page4.html" />
```

Comment: C#, and I'm already parsing the content. Currently I'm matching all of the Anchor tags, and only modifying the match if it meets critera. I'd prefer to have the initial regex match exclude the tags I don't want to modify.

Comment: Are you wanting to match closing tags as well?, `</a>` ?

Comment: No, I only want to match the opening tag to inject a Target="_top" attribute if it's an offsite url, and it doesn't already have a Target attribute.

Comment: If you're already parsing the content in C#, I'd leverage HTMLAgilityPack. From there, it's a simple LINQ query to find the tags you want to alter and the alterations are simplified as well.